# java - edit url parameter of a page and show editing as a hyperlink in same page

Tags: javascript, url, query-string, url-parameters, url-parsing

i need java code to get a part from URL when reload a page and put it in hyperlink and show it in same page.

**Example**

get google drive file id from page url while reload:

http//example.com#https//drive.google.com/open?id=**fileid**

.

and add it to this hyperlink with new parameter:

http//docs.google.com/uc?id=**fileid**&export=download

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

you cant try javascript regular expressions

```
var url = window.location.href;
var parts = url.match(/id=(\w+)/);
console.log(parts[1]);
```